# Why do I get a 403 response code when submitting changes at /admin/people/permissions?

Tags: civicrm

I have documented the warnings and notices I get
in the drupal watchdog logs at this link:

https://gist.github.com/hesco/1797208819f7b239d8be9deca6b8bac4

I see nothing in apache2 error logs.

I see a WSOD with the message: `Not allowed.` in the browser.
I see the 403 code in the browser inspect tool's js concole.
I also see that 403 in the apache2 access logs for every:
`POST /admin/people/permissions`

submitting the change for a specific user does not change the outcome.

Any thoughts on how I might debug this and resolve it would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-- Hugh